# save a loop while an matriz or a data frame

Tags: r, while-loop

I want to save a while in an matrix or in a data frame, in such a way that it places me in an orderly way

```
i <- 15#year
pon<-list()
while (i < 63) {
pon[i] <-cumprod( vlookup(i:62,Tabla_de_mortalidad_css,4))
 i = i+1}
```

this is my command that i am doing
I want you to print something like that: for example

```
v1 v2 v3
1
2  1
3  2  1
4  3  2
.  .  .
.  .  .
.  .  .
```

v1, v2, v3 are my variabl

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```
n <- 1:63
mat <- cbind(1:63, sapply(1:3, function(x) c(rep(NA, x), head(n, -x))))
mat

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    2    1   NA   NA
# [3,]    3    2    1   NA
# [4,]    4    3    2    1
# [5,]    5    4    3    2
# [6,]    6    5    4    3
# [7,]    7    6    5    4
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I still have a question, how do I make this command work for my code that I have above, that is,:` i <- 15 `# year
`while (i <63) {`
`put [i] <-cumprod (vlookup (i: 62, Mortality_Table_css, 4))`
`  i = i + 1}`
because I look for the the i in my table, in the range i: 62, and that result accumulates it for me, what I want is to save it in a data frame, where each i must be a column, but if you look at the next iteration It will be i = 16, that is, I need and so on for each of the columns.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing, what is `vlookup` etc.

Answer (score 1):

use `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
n <- 1:10
Lag <- 1:3

df <- data.frame(n = n)
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(Lag, ~transmute(df, !!paste0("Lag", .x) := lag(n, n = .x))))
#>     n Lag1 Lag2 Lag3
#> 1   1   NA   NA   NA
#> 2   2    1   NA   NA
#> 3   3    2    1   NA
#> 4   4    3    2    1
#> 5   5    4    3    2
#> 6   6    5    4    3
#> 7   7    6    5    4
#> 8   8    7    6    5
#> 9   9    8    7    6
#> 10 10    9    8    7
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I still have a question, how do I make this command work for my code that I have above, that is,` i <- 15` # year
`while (i <63) {`
`put [i] <-cumprod (vlookup (i: 62, Mortality_Table_css, 4))`
  `i = i + 1}`
because I look for the the i in my table, in the range i: 62, and that result accumulates it for me, what I want is to save it in a data frame, where each i must be a column, but if you look at the next iteration It will be i = 16, that is, I need and so on for each of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily with `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
do.call(cbind, shift(1:10, n = 1:3))
```

-output

```
#        [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1   NA   NA
# [3,]    2    1   NA
# [4,]    3    2    1
# [5,]    4    3    2
# [6,]    5    4    3
# [7,]    6    5    4
# [8,]    7    6    5
# [9,]    8    7    6
#[10,]    9    8    7
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I still have a question, how do I make this command work for my code that I have above, that is,` i <- 15` # year
`while (i <63) {`
`pon [i] <-cumprod (vlookup (i: 62, Mortality_Table_css, 4))`
`i = i + 1}`
because I look for the the i in my table, in the range i: 62, and that result accumulates it for me, what I want is to save it in a data frame, where each i must be a column, but if you look at the next iteration It will be i = 16, that is, I need and so on for each of the columns.